# Two boxes don't place themselves correctly, but the other does

Tags: html, css, block

Trying to make a website built up by boxes of different sizes.
Been mixing a lot with it but can't get this last thing to work.

EDIT: So, as you can se in the JSFiddle, the two last boxes are starting on a new row. I want them to be placed between the two mediumNews DIV and under the lineNews DIV. But they just start a new row. Here is a simple Paint note to show how I want it.

[Image of how I want it to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvPLS.jpg)

[JSFiddle Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/3Da7F/)

Here is also the code used in the JSFiddle:

HTML

```
    <div id="wrapNews">
    <div class="bigNews">
    L
    </div>

    <div class="mediumNews">
    M
    </div>

    <div class="lineNews">
    L
    </div>

    <div class="smallNews">
    S
    </div>

    <div class="smallNews">
    S
    </div>

    <div class="smallNews">
    S
    </div>

    <div class="smallNews">
    S
    </div>

    <div class="mediumNews">
    THEY SHOULD BE TO THE RIGHT OF THIS ONE...
    </div>

    <div class="lineNews">
    AND UNDER THIS ONE...
    </div>

    <div class="mediumNews">
    AND TO THE LEFT OF THIS ONE
    </div>

    <div class="smallNews">
    THIS BOX IS WRONG
    </div>

    <div class="smallNews">
    AND THIS ONE TO
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
background-image: url('bg3.jpg');
font-family: Helvetica;
}

#header {
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapNews {
width: 920px;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lineWrap {
overflow: hidden;
}

.smallNews {
display: inline-block;
width: 210px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid grey;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 10px;
}

.lineNews {
display: inline-block;
width: 440px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid grey;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 10px;
}

.mediumNews {
display: inline-block;
width: 210px;
height: 420px;
border: 1px solid grey;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 10px;
}

.bigNews {
display: inline-block;
width: 900px;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid grey;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: _"I think this JSFiddle will speak for it self!"_ It doesn't. Please explain the issue. And what's a "box-a-like website"?

Comment: @j08691 I updated my first post to try to better explain what you mentioned. Hope it's better now!

Comment: @Casper: [Like that?](http://jsfiddle.net/3Da7F/5/)

Comment: @Notulysses Yes, kinda like that! But, isn't there a solution that I can apply to "the whole code?" I built this the way that I can just add any box anywhere and the site will adapt, with this that wont work. Also, if I like zoom out and in the box positions will go weird at some zooms, only happends to the bottom boxes that has the placement problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `float:right` this `div` :

```
<div class="mediumNews" style="float:right">
    AND TO THE LEFT OF THIS ONE
</div>
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Da7F/8/)

Comment: That is also a solution :) But, iisn't there a solution that I can apply to "the whole code?" I built this the way that I can just add any box anywhere and the site will adapt, with this that wont work. If the answer is no, I'll use some of all the awesome answers I've gotten!

Comment: @Casper : It is not possible using `float` as I am concerned,but you can look forward using flex or grid layouts.If I were you I would add 2 classes for each element : first for appearance and second for positioning .[Look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/3Da7F/9/)

Comment: That is also a solution, but I were hoping to just have some simple done DIV's I always could use, like one big, one medium, one small etc. Just paste them in where I want and it will adapt, but from the answers I've gotten I guess that's not possible with simply CSS. But thanks for the help, your first solution was the simplest one :)